# Dictionary of lists code gives wrong output

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

In the following example I have data contained in a dictionary. After applying some code, the correct output should be the value *905*. My current code, however, produces the value *1296*, which is incorrect.

The variable *non_udacity_enollments* appears fine, since it gives the same output as the practice code I am learning from.

The code below is an adaptation of the practice code I am learning from.

```
non_udacity_enrollments=[]
non_udacity_enrollments[:] = [v for v in enrollments if v.get('is_udacity')=='False']
paid_students = {}

    for enrollment in non_udacity_enrollments:
        if (not enrollment['is_canceled'] or
                enrollment['days_to_cancel'] > 7):
            account_key = enrollment['account_key']
            enrollment_date = enrollment['join_date']

            if (account_key not in paid_students or
                    enrollment_date > paid_students[account_key]):
                paid_students[account_key] = enrollment_date
    len(paid_students)
```

I am trying to understand where it is that I am going wrong. Thanks.

As requested, here's the output of **print enrollments[0]**

{u'status': u'canceled', u'is_udacity': u'True', u'is_canceled': u'True', u'join_date': u'2014-11-10', u'account_key': u'448', u'cancel_date': u'2015-01-14', u'days_to_cancel': u'65'}

And the output of **print paid_students**

{u'199': u'2015-05-30', u'593': u'2015-04-02', u'1200': u'2015-03-04', u'1175': u'2015-04-02', u'1269': u'2015-08-21', u'1268': u'2015-04-06', u'1256': u'2015-07-18', u'669': u'2015-05-12', u'1257': u'2015-07-09', u'1145': u'2015-04-04', u'344': u'2015-01-11', u'345': u'2015-01-07', u'346': u'2014-12-08', u'347': u'2015-04-05', u'340': u'2015-04-01', u'341': u'2015-05-10', u'342': u'2014-12-05', u'343': u'2014-12-07', u'810': u'2014-11-10', u'919': u'2014-11-10', u'812': u'2015-07-09', u'813': u'2015-07-11', u'348': u'2015-03-05', u'349': u'2015-04-0....

Comment: what is enrollments?

Comment: can you show us your sample data?

Comment: @prashant enrollments is a dictionary similar to non_udacity_enrollments. I'm copying it to the latter to delete some values. I'll try posting code when back on my PC.

Comment: @DennisKioko can you show your sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the value of `is_canceled` is string, not boolean, so you can do `not enrollment['is_canceled']`, because that will be always true.

The same with the value of `days_to_cancel` - you are comparing unicode value with integer, that will also give you strange result.

So the condition should be something like this:

```
if (enrollment['is_canceled'] == 'False' or int(enrollment['days_to_cancel']) > 7):
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I have been stuck here for a week. Thanks a lot guys.